# C# DTO and WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api, dto

Our DTO's are in a separate assembly, and this is being shared between the server (web api) and client (winforms). The DTO class use DataAnnotations heavily, especially for maxlength.

In our forms, we have to set the maxlength for each and every control. The controls are bound to the dto objects using bindingsource.

Is there a way to extract the dataannotations information and set the controls' maxlength automatically on loading the form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Data Annotations attributes from model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638105/get-data-annotations-attributes-from-model)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve Data Annotations from code? (programmatically)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027613/how-to-retrieve-data-annotations-from-code-programmatically)